# Two moderator positions are available; why are there three choices?

Tags: support, moderator-election

The election phase of the 2017 Moderator Election has just begun. As can be seen from the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1), two moderator positions are available.

Therefore, I am surprised to see that we can choose three candidates (in the last elections there were always three open positions and three choices). Is this a mistake, or is a potential move-up candidate already considered?

I know that we are using [STV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) and [how it roughly works](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/20), but I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work if every voter just had two choices.

Comment: See: [How does Single Transferable Vote work?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/20/101)

Comment: I believe it is something akin to a Single Transferable Vote system, where if no candidate has enough votes to be declared a winner, the bottom candidate will be eliminated and their votes moved to the second choice, and so on until there is a clear winner.

Comment: @honk The more choices you give people, the better STV works.  Theoretically you'd want people to rank *all* of the candidates, not just a few, but in practice, most people don't have preferences after a certain point, so it's often *good enough* to cut people off at a certain point in order to avoid overwhelming the voter with decisions, and/or to simplify the actual voting process.

Comment: @davidism Of course, that one vote can be split up into fractions of a vote and go to multiple candidates from among your choices, not that you need to consider that when actually making your choices.

Comment: @davidism Consider three candidates, A, B, and C, for two positions.  Let's say A gets 60% of the vote, and we're using a system where 50% is needed for the position, so A has 10% more than they needed.  We can't just take 10% of the votes and go to their next choice; how do you decide which voters get to have their next choice count (keep in mind they won't all have the same second choice)?  Instead, you look at *everyone's* second choice, but only have it count for 10% (this number likely isn't quite right, but it'd be some fractional percentage) of a vote.

Comment: @davidism a different way to think of it would be to look at the 10% excess, and divide it up based on what percent of it is people's next choice, so for example if 40% of the people that voted for A had B as their next choice, 40% of that 10% excess would go to B (and 60% of the 10% to C).  This is how it's easiest to calculate things from the perspective of the vote tallier (rather than thinking of it as however many fractional votes), but they'd be analogous.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Having three choices is a highly useful voting mechanism even if there's only a *single* position available.

If your first choice vote is eliminated, then you're able to have your second choice vote considered, rather than simply having the vote go away.  Likewise, if your second choice candidate is eliminated, it can go to your third choice.

Along the same lines (and this one only applies when there are multiple positions to fill), if your top candidate vote wins, and wins by more than they need to get the position, the next choice of the candidates can be considered as well (proportional to the amount of the excess votes).

The effect of doing these things is that it doesn't punish people for voting for an unlikely candidate, if that's who they most want to win, and it doesn't punish people for voting for the *most* popular candidate, even if they want them to win.

If you only had one vote (or two) and you voted for a longshot candidate that you liked the most, you'd be throwing your vote away, as they wouldn't win, and you'd have no say in who, among the top few candidates, should be given the position.  If you vote for the most popular candidate, and you only had one (or two) votes, then you'd *also* be throwing the vote away, as they were going to win without the vote, so you're not giving yourself a say in the other positions.

So by giving you *more* votes than there are positions, you're able to vote freely, for whomever you want to be a moderator most (in the order of your preferences) and you'll be able to know that that will be in your own best interests.  If you had less votes, you'd be forced to consider how you think other people would vote, and vote strategically based on that, rather than being able to vote for who you actually want to win.

Comment: // , This does ot solve the problem of strategic voting.

Comment: @NathanBasanese why not? Why would you choose another person, than you actualy want?

Comment: @NathanBasanese With SO's implementation, that's correct, because there's only 3 votes.  If you were allowed to rank *every* candidate in order, there would be zero need for strategic voting at all.  As it is you basically get one "free" vote that doesn't need to be strategic (or at least doesn't need to be optimal, depending on which you prefer), but you need to think about the other two.